# Sheaf cohomology relative to a closed subspace

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $i : A \hookrightarrow X$ be a closed subspace of a topological space $X$, and $j : Z := X \setminus A \hookrightarrow X$ denote its open complement. Given a sheaf $F$ of abelian groups on $X$, one can define sheaf cohomology with support in $A$, by taking the derived functors of the functor $\Gamma_A$ "sections with support in $A$":
$$\Gamma_A F := \lbrace s \in \Gamma(X,F): s_{|Z} = 0 \rbrace.$$
Whenever the spaces involved are nice enough, and $F$ is a constant sheaf, these derived functors seem to give the relative singular cohomology groups $H^*(X,Z)$.

I am wondering the following:

1. How can we rewrite the expression $R^q \Gamma_A F$ in terms of the functors direct and inverse images associated with $i$ (or $j$) ? That is, can we define the sheaf $R^q \Gamma_A F$ as $R^q i_* i^* F$, or something in this spirit ?
2. What if I would like to obtain the relative cohomology groups $H^*(X,A)$ ? In this case, could we define relative sheaf cohomology as something like $R^q j_* j^* F$ ?
3. What would be the properties of the functors used to define cohomology relative to the closed $A$ (left adjoint, exact...) ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $j:X\backslash A\to X$  and $i:A\to X$ denote the inclusions. Let $j_!$ denote the functor of extension by zero along $j$. Then the relative cohomology is exactly $H^*(X,j_!R)$ where $R$ is the constant sheaf of coefficients. To see this, just consider the exact sequence

$$j_!j^*R\to R \to i_*i^*R$$ and observe that the second map is identified with restriction along $i$ after passing to global sections.

The general scheme to have in mind is that we have 6-functors formalism here:

$i^*$ and $j^*$ are restrictions, $i_*$ and $j_*$ are the usual push maps, right adjoint to $i^*$ and $j_*$. Additinally we have 
$i_!,i^!,j_!,j^!$ where:

$i_! = i_*$.

$j^!=j^*$.

$j_!$ is extension by zero.

$i^!$ is "sections with support on $A$".

And we have the basic exact triangles of functors 
$i_!i^!\to Id\to j_*j^*$ 
and $j_!j^! \to Id \to i_*i^*$.

From those facts you can more or less deduce anything related to the way sheaves and their sections on $X$ decompose into the open and closed part.

Comment: Thanks a lot @S. Carmeli. What is the difference between $j_!$ and $j_*$ ? If $F$ is a sheaf on $X$, then should I define $R^* j_! j^* F$, or $R^* j_! j^! F$, or something else ? What properties does this functor have ?

Comment: I edited the answer to contain more information. and in general open-closed decomposition is a place where its much easier to understand things on the level of the derived category rather then on the cohomology ($R^*(\bullet)$), so I strongly suggest to try to learn some derived categories in order to understand what's going on here on the cohomological level.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I think you made a small writing mistake: "right adjoint to $i^*$ and $j^*$" instead of $j_*$. Last question, does the functor $j_!$ have nice properties, for instance, does it commute with direct sums, derived functors, restrictions etc ?

Comment: If I understand you well, given a sheaf $F$ on $X$, I will define $R^* j_! j^* F$ for relative sheaf cohomology with respect to $A$, and $R^* i_* i^! F$ for relative cohomology with respect to $Z$ ?

Comment: The notation $R^*$ in your comment is non-standard at least. It should be $R^*\Gamma(X,\bullet)$ or so. But again, its a good idea to shift to derived categories and don't take cohomologies. In this context its very helpful.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I meant $R^* \Gamma(X,.)$ instead of $R^*$. But except that, the functors where well-placed ?

Comment: Of course, I'll try to read about derived categories for a better understanding (do you happen to have a good reference ?). For now though, I need only to understand what functors are involved and what are their properties (commutativity with direct sums, direct limits, higher direct images, cohomology etc).

Comment: The correct functor computing the cohomoloy relative to $A$ is $R^*\Gamma(X,j_!j^*F)$

Comment: In general, the functors $j_!$ and $i^*$ commute with colimits and $i^!$ and $j_*$ with limits. The functors $j^*$ and $i_*$ commutes with both. All those properties follows from the adjunctions $(f_!,f^!)$ and $(f^*,f_*)$ for $f=i,j$, together with the isomorphisms $j^*=j^!$, $i_!=i_*$.

Comment: And what about coproducts and higher direct images ? Thanks a lot again

Comment: Maybe a last question if I may, does $i^*$ commute with cohomology ? That is, do we have that $$R^*\Gamma(A,i^*F) = i^* R^* \Gamma(X,F) ?$$

Comment: The question is not well defined, because the functor $i^*$ can not be applied to cohomology: Cohomology is not a sheaf on $X$ but an abelian group. It is, however, an exact functor.

Comment: I understand. So maybe my question would better be something like: if $F$ is the constant sheaf on $X$, do we have that $i^*F$ is the constant sheaf on A ? To go back to $j_! j^*$, do you know if it usually commutes with higher direct images and coproducts ?